# Google Analytics content experiments with dynamic urls

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing, google-experiments

I'm looking into setting up a content experiment for my site. All the documentation states to  set the url for the original page and then set up variations of this page at different urls.

The issue I have is that my product pages all have different urls like below

http://example.com/jeans/meddi/blue/
http://example.com/tops/inkle/black/

I want the experiment to run on ALL product pages.

It seems that by using a server side implementation I can determine which experiment to display and then call the setChosenVariation method to inform GA which variation has been shown to the user.

My issue is that when initially setting up the experiment with the GA interface it asks for the url of the original page and then the variation pages. But in my case I don't have a http://example.com/product.php url that I can use for the original.

Also with the server side implementation is it necessary to alter the url of the variations if I'm essentially choosing the variation and setting this within the GA javascript API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Content Experiments Without Redirects (Browser-only implementation)

https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side